# Super+D (show desktop) changes which value?

Tags: dconf, python3

In my python program I want to detect if the desktop is to be shown (all windows minimized). How do I do this? Which value (perhaps in dconf) is set when the user hits Super+D?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wmctrl (Window Manager Control) program to get information about and influence your window manager. In your case you will want to use the -m switch to get the window manager information.

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: ON
```

The last line is the one you are interested in.

Comment: Looks good, but how can I use it with python?

;import wmctrl;

dir(wmctrl) lists nothing like "show_mode" or something.